# onClick Prompt Href Javascript Code

Tags: javascript, href, prompt

Is it possible to make a button that whenever a person clicks it a prompt shows up when he enters the age or name it redirects him to a page.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes. What have you tried. What have you searched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Ultimate/WfrsN/

```
$('#prompt').click(function(){
   var name = prompt("Enter your name");
    if(name != ""){
        window.location = "http://www.example.com/" + name;
    } else {
        alert("You did not fill in a name!");
    }
});
```

Something like that?